# How can I check input type file or hidden in laravel in controller

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check input type file or hidden in laravel in controller from view.

```
    @if(isset($input_data['list_image_filename1']))
        <label for="list_image_filename1">{{ $input_data['list_image_filename1'] }}</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="list_image_filename1" value="{{ $input_data['list_image_filename1'] }}">
    @else
        <input class="form-control" name="list_image_filename1" type="file" id="list_image_filename1">
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function processForm(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->file('list_image_filename1')) {
        //  it's file input
    } elseif ($request->has('list_image_filename1')) {
        // it's hidden input
    }
}
```